# CMake's equivalent to Visual Studio's Property Sheets (.vsprops)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clion, vsprops

I'm trying to migrate from Visual Studio towards Jetbrains' (awesome) [CLion IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) which uses [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) to organize the projects.

Until now, the transition has been smooth: creating CMake projects and importing them into CLion is easy, and I can begin coding on one plateform then continue on another one without problems.

However, one aspect of Visual Studio that I couldn't find an equivalent to in CMake is [property sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): I use them mainly for holding the include directories' paths and the linking libs for libraries (i.e. one `.vsprops` file for each library, e.g. `OpenCV.vsprops`, `Boost.vsprops`, etc.).

This way, in VS, I could share a library's `.vsprops` file between different projects without having to configure the paths/libs each time.

Does CMake have a similar mechanism to Visual Studio's property sheets ? How is it possible to store a library's includes/libs in a *CMake-parsable* file then "import" it in CMakeLists.txt in order to link against the library ?

Basically, what I want to do is:

1. Create a "cmake property sheet" (for lack of a better name) for a given library.
2. Then, in CMakeLists.txt, write something like `link_target_to_libs(myTarget "path/to/propertySheet1" "path/to/propertySheet2" ...)` .

Comment: ***How can I emulate Visual Studio's property sheets (for libraries) in CMake ?*** You have to generate these yourself using cmake commands to create files.

Comment: ***I use them mainly for holding the include directories' paths and the linking libs for libraries*** I would just use CMake's handling if libraries and include files. Or are you meaning to not create your Visual Studio projects with CMake.

Comment: I've edited the last part of my post in order to clarify my intentions :) And you are right, I don't want to use VS anymore. I just want to have CMake projects which source code I'm going to edit using CLion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I really want to make the libraries' inclusion/linking into a one-line command, and as far as my (basic) knowledge of CMake goes, I think that some compromise should be made -- mainly sharing the target name's **variable** between `CMakeLists.txt` and the "property sheets". So this is my solution... until someone proposes a simpler/cleaner one:

1. A *CMake property sheet* is a `.cmake` text file,
2. A *well-known variable name* --`TARGET`-- designates the target (i.e. the first argument of `add_executable()`),
3. Aside from library-specific commands, a `.cmake` file contains a call to `target_include_directories(${TARGET} PRIVATE ${PATH_TO_INCLUDE_DIR})` and `target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${LIST_OF_LIBS})`,
4. In order to use/link against a library, call `include("path/to/.cmake")` in `CMakeLists.txt`.

I have successfully built and executed a simple program that uses X11 and OpenCV with the following files:

**x11.cmake**

```
target_include_directories(${TARGET} PRIVATE "/usr/include/X11")
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so")
```

**opencv.cmake**

```
# OpenCV-specific stuff
set(OpenCV_DIR "/PATH/TO/OPENCV/INSTALL/DIR/share/OpenCV") # path to OpenCVConfig.cmake
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
# include path
target_include_directories(${TARGET} PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# linking libs
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} opencv_world opencv_ts)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(hello_clion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

## hello-clion ##############################
# make a new target name
set(TARGET hello-clion)

# find sources
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cpp" "src/*.hpp")

# declare a target
add_executable(${TARGET} ${SOURCE_FILES})

# link the libraries (to the last-declared ${TARGET}, which should be the last-added executable)
include("x11.cmake")
include("opencv.cmake")
#############################################
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <thread>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <Xlib.h>

int main_x11()
{
    // adapted from: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Window_creation/X11#Xlib
}

int main_ocv()
{
    // adapted from: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#source-code
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    thread tocv(main_ocv);
    thread tx11(main_x11);

    tocv.join();
    tx11.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, each time I want to use OpenCV in a project/program, I just have to put `include("opencv.cmake")` in the corresponding `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: That won't be a good solution when you define multiple targets in one directory. I suggest you look at the docs links I provided.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this solution might be problematic, please ? I can see that the *include* path might be *polluted* (i.e. contain unnecessary directories) but that, I think, isn't an issue... is it ?

Comment: I've edited my solution to use `target_include_directories()` in order to have per-target include directories.

Answer (score 1):

In CMake, libraries can export a package with IMPORTED targets which other buildsystems import using find_package:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-packages.7.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets

Instead of 'linking to property sheets', you link to the IMPORTED targets.

```
target_link_libraries(myTarget Dep1::Dep1 Dep2::Dep2)
```

Not all libraries create IMPORTED targets, and not all provide cmake config-file packages. In those cases (including OpenCV and Boost), CMake provides find modules:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules

which you use with find_package and link to the contents of variables.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work great, but there could certainly be problems I haven't discovered.  (I was worried multiple macros adding the same target_link_libraries would cause "already defined" linking errors , but at least g++ 5.1.0 handles being given the same library name multiple times without error.)

In root CMakeLists.txt, **BEFORE** add_subdirectory() calls or globs, include:

```
macro(USES_WX)
    include_directories(SYSTEM /usr/local/include/wx-3.0)
    include_directories(SYSTEM /usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.0)
    link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
    add_definitions(-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET} pthread wx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0 wx_gtk3u_html-3.0 wx_gtk3u_qa-3.0 wx_gtk3u_adv-3.0 wx_gtk3u_core-3.0 wx_baseu_xml-3.0 wx_baseu_net-3.0 wx_baseu-3.0)
endmacro()
```

(You can make the macro more fancy, like checking for if CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is "Debug" or "Release" to link to the appropriate libraries, vary preprocessor definitions, etc.  See http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html)

And have your project's CMakeLists.txt be like this:

```
set(TARGET myProgramName)
add_executable(${TARGET} myProgramName.cpp)
USES_WX()
```

^^ The macro call **MUST** be after add_executable()

---

And, if you want multiple target support, modify the line in the root CMakeLists.txt section shown above to:

```
    ...
    target_link_libraries(${ARGV0} pthread wx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0 ...)
    ...
```

And have your project's CMakeLists.txt be like this (less lines, but more chance for error):

```
add_executable(myProgramName myProgramName.cpp)
USES_WX(myProgramName)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I should say that I have improved my solution by "encapsulating" the contents of the `.cmake` property sheets inside functions that take for input the name of the target (I don't have to rely on a global `TARGET` variable anymore). Also, I have made a `add_executable()`-like function that takes care of managing the property sheets' inclusion etc. It has actually some similarities with what you've suggested :)

Comment: If I have time, I'll put my final solution in my public repo or somewhere.. might prove useful for people who, like me, have a local repo of libs and need a quick, 1-line-mechanism for using them in their cmake-based projects...

Comment: That would be great if you could put it up somewhere.  I'd be happy to see a better / different solution.